How can I fix this code for a "unpublish comment" link on each comment?
I built a custom module for the purpose of providing moderators with the ability to unpublish (or 'unapprove') a comment by clicking a link that appears on the comment.
The module provides the link and I have the template displaying it. But clicking the link appears to reroute to the page without unpublishing the comment.

No related errors appear in the log
This is Drupal 10.3.0
The module machine name is unpubcomms

So I seem to be missing something.
I'm sure there are other problems here. I have only written a couple of super-basic custom modules before--and only with a lot of help.
This is the .module file.
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\comment\Entity\Comment;

/**
 * Implements hook_comment_links_alter().
 */
function unpubcomms_comment_links_alter(array &$links, Comment $entity, array &$context) {
  if ($entity->isPublished() && \Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('administer comments')) {
    $links['unpublish'] = [
      'title' => t('Unpublish'),
      'url' => \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('unpubcomms.comment_unpublish', ['comment' => $entity->id()]),
    ];
  }
}

/**
 * Access callback for the comment unpublish route.
 */
function unpubcomms_comment_unpublish_access(Comment $comment, AccountInterface $account) {
  return AccessResult::allowedIf($account->hasPermission('administer comments') && $comment->isPublished());
}

This is the routing.yml file.
unpubcomms.comment_unpublish:
  path: '/comment/{comment}/unpublish'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\unpubcomms\Controller\UnpubcommsController::unpublish'
    _title: 'Unpublish Comment'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer comments'

This is the UnpubcommsController.php file.
<?php

namespace Drupal\unpubcomms\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\comment\Entity\Comment;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class UnpubcommsController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Unpublishes a comment.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\comment\Entity\Comment $comment
   *   The comment to unpublish.
   *
   * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
   *   A redirect back to the commented entity.
   */
  public function unpublish(Comment $comment) {
    // Unpublish the comment.
    $comment->setPublished(FALSE);
    $comment->save();

    // Redirect back to the content entity.
    return new RedirectResponse($comment->getCommentedEntity()->toUrl()->toString());
  }

}

I'm guessing I've overlooked something really basic, but I'm not seeing it.

Have you used XDebug?  If you put a breakpoint on $comment->save(), what do you see?

I would set a message:
$this->messenger()->addStatus($this->t('Comment has been unpublished!'));

This has two advantages, you get feedback and it helps with caching because browsers don't cache the redirect when you send the cookie for the message.
The main problem, though, seems to be the deprecated usage of
$comment->setPublished(FALSE);

This doesn't work anymore, the argument FALSE is ignored. You have to use
$comment->setUnpublished();


That works. Thanks!
